# how to write stored recursive procedure in order to get hierarchical element

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, hierarchy, recursive-query

hello i have table profile that has many attributs, and the profile has on parent but the parent can have a parent etc..
I want to get all the list of the attributs(even the attributs of the parents)
i wrote this stored procedure with mysql 5.1.42 but it returns only the attributs of the profile without including the attributs of the parents
...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_all_attributes`(IN profile_id INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL;

  -- Get the attributes for the current profile
  SELECT
    Id, attribut_rank, attribut_type, create_date, editor, label, memo, name, profile
  FROM 
    marketing_profile_attribut
  WHERE 
    profile = profile_id
  ORDER BY 
    attribut_rank;

  -- Get the parent ID for the current profile
  SELECT 
    parent
  INTO
    parent_id
  FROM
    marketing_profile
  WHERE 
    Id = profile_id;

  -- If the parent ID is not null, call the stored procedure recursively with the parent ID
  IF parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    CALL get_all_attributes(parent_id);
  END IF;
END
...
```

please can you tell me what is wrong with this procedure i am working with mysql 5.1.42

Comment: Do not use recursive SP, iterate in it (```REPEAT .. UNTIL NOT ROW_COUNT()```). Use temporary table and collect your data into it. Finally select everything from this table. *what is wrong with this procedure* I predict that you look for the former rowset produced by SP only whereas it returns a collection of rowsets, 2 rowset per recursion level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this exactly as it is (it works on my db):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_all_attributes2`(IN p_profile INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE not_found INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
    
  DECLARE cur_data CURSOR FOR
  SELECT parent
  FROM marketing_profile
  WHERE Id = p_profile;
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = TRUE;    
    
    SET @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 100;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_attributes (
    Id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    memo VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
    label VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    editor INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    attribut_type INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    profile INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    create_date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    attribut_rank INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
  );
    
    -- insert the attributes of p_profile into temporary table
    INSERT INTO temp_attributes
  SELECT Id, name, memo, label, editor, attribut_type, profile, create_date, attribut_rank
  FROM marketing_profile_attribut
  WHERE profile = p_profile;
    
    OPEN cur_data;
  data_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur_data
        INTO parent_id;
    IF not_found THEN
      LEAVE data_loop;
    END IF;
        CALL get_all_attributes2(parent_id);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_data;
    
  select * from temp_attributes
    order by attribut_rank;
        
    DROP TABLE temp_attributes;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the MySQL's `max_sp_recursion_depth` setting. As you are only looking for direct parents from the tree you can use a cursor loop instead of the recursion.

The best solution is to update your old MySQL version to a newer one and you can use common table expressions for that.

Comment: yes it is done , 
thank you for your answer, but i need to get all parents

Comment: OP does not receive an error. So he does not reach the limit.

Comment: @Akina. OP did not say if he received an error or not. The error message depends on the client. Some clients may not show the error. The code itself is ok.

Comment: SP returns the output. OP tells: "*it returns only the attributs of the profile without including the attributs of the parents*".

Comment: @Akina This is exactly what would happen when `max_sp_recursion_depth` has the default value 0. The first query would go through, but the recursice call is rejected. The code itself is ok.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that make the procedure doesn't work properly.

1. max_sp_recursion_depth: if it assumes value of 0 this makes the procedure not recursive and stops the execution when you try to call the same procedure that is running.
2. the select from marketing_profile_attribut is local and live only in the current istance! Each istance called in recursive way will produce only an entry. You need a structure in which you can store the results.

Considering the two points abobe the procedure could be something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_all_attributes`(IN profile_id INT)
BEGIN
    
  DECLARE parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table
    AS SELECT
    Id, attribut_rank, attribut_type, create_date, editor, label, memo, name, profile
    FROM 
    marketing_profile_attribut;
    
    SET @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 100;
        
  -- Get the attributes for the current profile
  INSERT INTO temp_table(Id, create_date)
  SELECT
    Id, attribut_rank, attribut_type, create_date, editor, label, memo, name, profile
  FROM 
    marketing_profile_attribut
  WHERE 
    profile = profile_id
  ORDER BY 
    Id;
        
  -- Get the parent ID for the current profile
  SELECT 
    parent
  INTO
    parent_id
  FROM
    marketing_profile
  WHERE 
    Id = profile_id;

  -- If the parent ID is not null, call the stored procedure recursively with the parent ID
  IF parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    CALL get_all_attributes(parent_id);
  else
      select * from temp_table;
      DROP TABLE temp_table;
    end if;
END
```

Comment: i set global variable using mysql server 
but when i used this function the results are null, it dosn't return even the attributs of the profile

Comment: It is strange, I have tested it and it returns the list of attribures! without setting any global variable.

Answer (score 0):

in fact there were exceptions
for that i made some corrections.. the resulting function
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_all_attributes`(IN profile_id INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE parent_id INT DEFAULT NULL;

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table
AS SELECT
Id, attribut_rank, attribut_type, create_date, editor, label, memo, name, profile
FROM
marketing_profile_attribut
where profile=   profile_id
group by Id
;


SET @@max_sp_recursion_depth = 100;
```

-- Get the attributes for the current profile
INSERT INTO temp_table (Id, attribut_rank, attribut_type, create_date, editor, `label`, memo, name, profile)

SELECT
Id, attribut_rank, attribut_type, create_date, editor, label, memo, name, profile
FROM
marketing_profile_attribut
WHERE
profile = profile_id
ORDER BY
Id;

-- Get the parent ID for the current profile
SELECT
parent
INTO
parent_id
FROM
marketing_profile
WHERE
Id = profile_id;

-- If the parent ID is not null, call the stored procedure recursively with the parent ID
IF parent_id IS NOT NULL THEN
CALL get_all_attributes(parent_id);
else

```
  select * from temp_table group by Id order by (attribut_rank);

end if;
```

END